# xpath: extract the trailing text of a node

Tags: xpath, xquery, xidel

I have an html file of the following content.

```
...
<table><tbody>
...
            <tr>
              <td><span class="myclass">C</span>
                <a href="/myurl" title="myclick">mytext</a>
                   tailing text
              </td>
            </tr>
...
</tbody></table>
...
```

I would like to extract the info and write to a TSV file in the following format.

```
C<TAB>mytext<T>tailing text
```

So far, I can only figure this xpath code to extract the first two columns. Could anybody show me how to extract the 3rd column? Thanks.

```
xidel -s -e '//table/tbody/tr/td/join((span, a), x:cps(9))' - < infile.html
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `//table/tbody/tr/td/string-join(node()[normalize-space()], x:cps(9))` you get three columns but the last might contain whitespace before and after the text so perhaps `//table/tbody/tr/td/string-join(node()[normalize-space()]/normalize-space(), x:cps(9))` is ensuring you don't get whitespace you haven't shown in your desired result.

Comment: I got an extra TAB in the 2nd column. Do you know why? `xidel -s --xpath '//table/tbody/tr/td/string-join(node()/normalize-space(), x:cps(9))' - <<< '<table><tbody> <tr> <td><span class="myclass">C</span> <a href="/myurl" title="myclick">mytext</a> tailing text </td> </tr> </tbody></table>' |cat -T` output `C^I^Imytext^Itailing text`

Comment: Well, you didn't use what I suggested, rather a variation that picks up white space text nodes as well, even if reduced to an empty string. To prevent that I had used a predicate `[normalize-space()]` in both suggestions which you have removed.

Comment: But I need the trailing empty field even when there is no trailing text.

Comment: Then you need to explain which text nodes you want and which ones not. Perhaps the answer by zx485 with `a/following-text()` is what you want, it explicitly selects the `span` child, the `a` child and the text following the `a` child while I tried to select any the text of any child that, after white space normalization, has text content. But that approach doesn't work if you expect to read out white space after the `a` element.

Comment: `//table/tbody/tr/td/join((span, a, a/following::text()[1], a/@href), x:cps(9))` is what I need (I added the need to href). But it is too slow. But your code seems to be much faster, but it trims empty fields that I still want to keep. I am wondering if there is anything can be done to achieve a fast performance yet keep the empty trailing field.

Comment: @user1424739, perhaps ask a new question about the performance issue, the only error I made yesterday when typing the previous comment that I put `a/following-text()` in there was that I wanted to type `a/following-sibling::text()`, as in the other answer. Using `following::sibling` might indeed be costly. On the other hand you said in the comment to the suggestion on zx485's response that even `a/following-sibling::text()` doesn't perform as you need it. I am not familiar with implementation details of xidel and performance questions are better answered by someone with detailed knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
xidel infile.html --xpath '//table/tbody/tr/td/string-join((span, "<TAB>", a, "<T>", a/following::text()[1]))'
```

or

```
xidel --xpath '//table/tbody/tr/td/string-join((span, "<TAB>", a, "<T>", a/following::text()[1]))' - < infile.html
```

Another approach is

```
xidel infile.html --xpath '//table/tbody/tr/td/concat(span, "<TAB>", a, "<T>", a/following-sibling::text()[1])'
```

The output is - in all three cases:

```
C<TAB>mytext<T>tailing text
```

Comment: This seems to be very slow when there are many `tr`s. Is it because of `a/following::text()[1]`? Thanks.

Comment: Another approach is `xidel infile.html --xpath '//table/tbody/tr/td/concat(span, "<TAB>", a, "<T>", a/following-sibling::text()[1])'`. But this is the absolute minimum. I doubt that it gets any better. The performance issues probably occur due to the `//` in the expression, because this checks _all tables in the whole document_.

Comment: I don't think `//` is the issue as removing `a/following-sibling::text()[1]` makes the run finish much faster. Are you saying `//` combining with `a/following-sibling::text()[1]` cause the performance problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you preserved the whitespace in your 'infile.html' (as seen in the OP)? If so, then you should see `a/following::text()[1]` returning 3 lines; `tailing text` with lots of whitespace around it. Also, OP wants to create a TSV file, so I doubt a literal "<TAB>" and "<T>" as a string is what he/she is after.

Comment: @Reino Yes. I need the TAB character.